# Interviewing Questions on Teaching

Tags: united-states, teaching, job-search, liberal-arts-colleges

I've got an interview for tenure-track teaching jobs at an R1 and liberal arts college in the US. As part of the application, they've seen a cover letter, CV, teaching statement, 3 syllabi, and diversity statement.

If they've already seen all this, what kind of questions will they ask about teaching at interviews? Do I still prepare the same kinds of questions and just expand more on the materials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look on the university web site for some statement of philosophy of the institution. I'll note that "R1 liberal arts" colleges are pretty rare and those I know of have high standards. Harvard comes to mind. UC Berkeley doesn't. My undergrad (liberal arts) place had a very complete, though short, statement about what was expected of students. A lot could be inferred from that about what was hoped for in professors.

The questions will possibly (probably?) be about your teaching philosophy. How you approach it, how you deal with students, etc. The judgements, while individual, might be in terms of that general philosophy.

One often disfavored philosophy is "Sink or Swim". Think about your goals in teaching. What is most important? What is your responsibility? What do you expect from students? Think about that. I don't want to give you my script.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - and I'm glad it's what I suspected and have been preparing!